# How can I count the number of open connections in an sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite, database-connection

I would like to count the number of open connections in an sqlite database. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [these](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg25752.html) [posts](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/iIs-it-possible-to-determine-how-many-open-connections-are-active-for-a-sqlite-database-td25290.html) on the mailing list there is no way to check the number of open connections through code or the database itself. There is no API.

According to [this post](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg25762.html), if you are running on a POSIX type system you can use the `lsof` command to count how many processes have opened the database.

If you are on Windows you can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to count the number of connections with the following steps:

1. In Process Explorer click on 'Find' -> Find Handle or DLL...
2. Type in the name of your sqlite database and click on 'Search' (or hit Enter)
3. In the results window, click on your database. It will become highlighted as a 'file' in the main Process Explorer window.
4. Back in the main window, right-click on your database file and click Properties
5. You can now see the number of References and Handles

Comment: This has been open for a few days. Accepting my own answer for now but I'm definitely open to other suggestions.

Comment: this is a handy tip. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

An open file monitor like `lsof` will do it

```
lsof dbName.sql
```

will give you list of connection

```
OpenerName 6158 User   39u   REG    1,2    20480 20397113 dbName.sql
```